# Updating Devepxress AspxGrid with inline edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an ASPxGrid with data pulled in from a database from multiple tables. I want to inline edit two cells. 
I need to update the the table with the data values and then show that change in the data grid. I am not sure how to achieve this. I am usinng a rowupdating event. Then take edited values and want to insert into database. This si what i have or an idea of what i need to do.

```
 protected void ASPxGridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    //DoUpdate(e);

    ASPxGridView gridView = (ASPxGridView)sender;

    gridView.CancelEdit();
    e.Cancel = true;

}
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [ASPxGridView - How to implement CRUD operations with a custom data source](https://www.devexpress.com/issue=KA18686) KB Article.